# Simple - friend declaration c++

Tags: c++, class, friend

short question - why do I get this message?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you trying to make a `char*` a friend?

Comment: What's the use of friend variables?

Comment: Please post text rather than pictures when possible. Apart from that, you get the message because there's no such thing as a friend variable.

Comment: I can't even see the message. Please don't use screen shots.

Comment: What is `friend char* NameVar;` supposed to do?

Comment: I want to make my private variables be accessable in classes, where I write `friend class CMesh`

Comment: @Jan021981, `friend class CMesh;` means `CMesh` can access that class's private stuff, not the other way around.

Comment: No, it's ok - I thought, I can also use that for variables, not only for functions....

Comment: @Jan021981 How would a variable access something from another class?? That makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 2):

A class can declare another class or a function as its friend. A variable cannot be made a friend of a class. If you think about it a bit more, it would make sense. A variable has a value. It does not need access to another class for it to be useful. A function or class, on other hand, may require access to the private and protected sections of other classes for its implementation.

More on the topic can be seen at https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.friend.

A snippet from that page:

> A friend of a class is a function or class that is given permission to use the private and protected member names from the class. A class specifies its friends, if any, by way of friend declarations.

Answer (score 0):

You make classes friends of each other. You cannot make a char pointer a friend. Read up on this http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/friend-class-function-cpp/

Comment: Ok, looking at that http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend I thought it's possible, to make only a part of the private class members accessable.

Comment: It's an older class I'm using, and I just make the private parts visible, when initializing it. Else if, I have to write functions that will only be used once at initialization....

Comment: If you want to make a private part externally visible, why make it private in the first place?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux look at the example, you may want certain classes to be able to see private parts that others don't. In the example they use it's helpful to let a linked list class look at nodes but you don't want any other class to be able to edit those nodes.

Comment: @Kilbo I understand the benefits of `friend` but Jan021981 seems to be trying to make members just `friend` *in general*. I wants to "make private parts visible" without specifying any constraints. It's the intention that confuses me.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux My bad, I thought you were just asking in general what the point of a friend class is. I see his comments now.